# bottle framework: getting requests and routing to work

Tags: python, bottle

I have written a webapp using traditional cgi. I'm now trying to rewrite it with bottle

The page is simple...the user fills out a form, hits submit and the data object is sent to a python script that used to live in my cgi-bin

The python script generates an image, and prints the url for that image out to standard out

On callback, I use javascript to display the newly generated image on the page formatted with html.

The issue that I'm having with bottle is getting the image-generating script to execute when it receives the post request. I'm used to handling the post request and callback with javascript (or jquery). should I be using a bottle method instead?

Comment: I actually resolved the issue. The Bottle framework tutorial encourages first-time users to set up the server on a high port (to avoid conflict with apache, etc) for development. I was missing two parts of the process:
1. import the python script so that it can be called from the main bottle file
2. in the main bottle file, add a route to the api link (for the javascript to work)

I'm not sure if I would have had to add the route if I was running the server on port 80

Comment: If you resolved the issue, please write your own answer and accept it. This way, the question won't be on the ‘unanswered’ page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually resolved the issue. The Bottle framework tutorial encourages first-time users to set up the server on a high port (to avoid conflict with apache, etc) for development. I was missing two parts of the process: 1. import the python script so that it can be called from the main bottle file 2. in the main bottle file, add a route to the api link (for the javascript to work) I'm not sure if I would have had to add the route if I was running the server on port 80